# How do you update a record with apache cayenne without using select clause

Tags: java, apache-cayenne

I am using apache cayenne 3.1. I know of one way to update records in the database is to first use select query to find record and then update it, but I don't want to use a select query for updating. How can I directly update the record?

Answer (score 0):

[EJBQLQuery](https://cayenne.apache.org/docs/3.1/cayenne-guide/queries.html#ejbqlquery) allows to do direct DB updates. Also [SQLTemplate](https://cayenne.apache.org/docs/3.1/cayenne-guide/queries.html#sqltemplate), though in that case you are completely breaking with the object model, and will be writing DB-specific SQL.